# Error in mysql database in Qt

Tags: mysql, qt, qt5

I wrote this sql codes in qt5 in ubuntu. I want to update a table. But I received following error:

> QSqlError(1065, "QMYSQL: Unable to execute query", "Query was empty")

This is my sql code:

```
       query4.prepare("update food_main set cost=:material_cost,"+material+"=:material_num where name='"+material_name+"'");
       query4.bindValue(":material_cost",material_cost);
       query4.bindValue(":material_num",material__num);
       query4.exec();
```

I must say that my table updates every time I run my code but I have the error too. Table and columns and variables were made in right method. What should I do?

Comment: Just before the exec, if you dump query4 what does it say in the sql string?